# Pycharm Multiprocessing Error, What Can I Do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, multiprocessing

I'm facing a error with Pycharm when tried to use multiprocessing.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

inicio = time.perf_counter()


def calcula_soma():
    print('Iniciando a Funcao...')
    soma = 0
    for i in range(50_000_000):
        soma = soma + 1
    print('Calculo Finalizado!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cod1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calcula_soma)
    cod2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calcula_soma)

    cod1.start()
    cod2.start()

    cod1.join()
    cod2.join()

    fim = time.perf_counter()
    total = round(fim - inicio, 2)
    print(f'Tempo: {total}')
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:....\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.4\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:....\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.4\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:....\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\teste.py", line 19, in <module>
    cod1.start()
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function calcula_soma at 0x0000021CE30DE0E0>: attribute lookup calcula_soma on __main__ failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:....\Anaconda3\envs\teste\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

When I run it in Jupyter Notebook, the code works so this problem is about Pycharm. I google it and find out a lot of same problems with this error but none of resulutions helps me.

Comment: I would just not run the code in PyCharm. It's an IDE; you only execute code there to aid in debugging, not as your primary Python runtime.

Comment: Makes sense, do you think the Jupyter is better for this? If no, which one is your favorite?

Comment: I don't use IDEs. I just edit code using my preferred text editor and execute it directly from the command line with `python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time looking for a anwser, I didn't find quickly. So to help someone else this is what helps me.

The link about this issues is: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50116

**Solution**:

1. In menus bar go to Run/Debug Configurations

[image: Step 1]

2. Add a New Configuration

[image: Step 2]

3. Click on Python

[image: Step 3]

4. Rename the Configuration

[image: Step 4]

5. Select the script

[image: Step 5]

6. Uncheck the "Run with Python Console" option

[image: Step 6]

7. **DONE =D**